Why does /usr/bin/python3 report /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 as sys.executable?
I encountered a situation on macOS where the path reported by sys.executable is different from the Python interpreter I explicitly ran. Here's what I observed:

I started Python using `/usr/bin/python3`:
$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct  4 2024, 08:01:31) 
[Clang 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3     # different from /usr/bin/python3


I checked the /usr/bin/python3 file and found it is an actual binary, not a symbolic link:
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3
-rwxr-xr-x  78 root  wheel  118848 Nov 15 12:59 /usr/bin/python3



This behavior confuses me because: /usr/bin/python3 is not a symbolic link, so I expected sys.executable to match it. Instead, sys.executable points to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3.
Why? How can I ensure that the actual Python executable path matches the one I explicitly run?
Any insights or clarifications would be greatly appreciated!

When you install the commandline tools package for macOS, it installs shims (wrapper executables) in /usr/bin.
So /usr/bin/python3 isn't the Python interpreter, it's an executable that starts the Python interpreter.

If I haven’t installed the Command Line Tools, will /usr/bin/python3 still exist on the system? If it does, what is its functionality in this case?

It probably won't exist, or the shim will explain how to install the command line tools (can't remember).
